# Creating gtk signal for editing GtkWidget running in other thread

Tags: c, pthreads, gtk, signals

I have an app, which basically runs in terminal mode, but it can open it's GUI part in another thread (Simple window with a `GtkTextView` to print some messages out).
I need to manually update the contents of this `GtkTextView` when some event happens in main thread. For that purpose I created a **'new-message-received'** signal which should pass a pointer to char array **msg** with message to print

Creating new signal:

```
g_signal_new("new-message-received",
              G_TYPE_OBJECT, G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,
              0, NULL, NULL,
              g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__POINTER,
              G_TYPE_NONE, 1, G_TYPE_POINTER);
```

Connecting it with handler function:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(demo_window), "new-message-received", 
                 G_CALLBACK(print_demo_message),(gpointer)msg);
```

And emitting signal:

```
if (flag){
memset(msg, 0, 256);
g_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT(demo_window), 
                     "new-message-received", 
                     (gpointer) msg);
...
}
```

The problem is that signal handler gets some broken pointer (I try to print it to stdout -- it's always some random 4 symbols) instead of passed message.
The handler is:

```
void print_demo_message(gpointer *param)
{
    const gchar* message = (const gchar*)param;
    g_print("Got message: %s\n", message);
    ...
}
```

The output is like:

`Got message: p���`

What I tried:

1. Making `msg` a global variable to avoid re-initialization -- no
   result
2. Using a generic marshaller in signal creating -- no result
3. Passing a link to `msg` address instead of a pointer to it, no
   result too.

The question is -- what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to solve this myself, there was no need in using signals at all.

Main thread for GTK is a thread, where `gtk_main()` is called from. Accessing any GTK object outside it's main thread is forbidden. So, to initiate a thread for GTK GUI I used `g_thread_new()` and `g_idle_add(print_demo_message, msg)` to "ask" GTK main thread to paste the `msg` to `GtkTextView`.

So, now it look like this:

```
APP MAIN THREAD:

if(%some_condition%){
     msg = malloc(256);
     sprintf(msg, "Some text");
     g_idle_add(print_demo_message, msg);
}
```

---

```
GUI THREAD:

boolean print_demo_message(gpointer data)
{
    gchar* message = data;
    g_print("Got message: %s\n", message);
 ...
}
```

Message transferred OK, works like charm :)